# Slick2D drawString with coordinates from bottom-left corner

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick

For OpenGL text drawing I use Slick2D library. Default Slick2D `0:0` coordinates are at upper-left corner. But in my project I use bottom-left corner for `0:0`. Is it real to configure Slick2D with bottom-left corner as starting point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extended `AngelCodeFont` and `Image` classes to implement text drawing I need.

In `AngelCodeFont` I updated `yoffset` for each char:

```
def.yoffset = lineHeight - def.height - def.yoffset;
```

where lineHeight was parsed from `common` line in `.fnt` file.